# Nginx HTTP not working - downloads a file called "download"

Tags: nginx

if I visit my nginx site with https it is working, but with http it is downloading a file called "download" (no extension whatsoever), 57 bytes and opening it with notepad etc just shows gibberish stuff.

Here's my vhost config:

```
server {
    server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
    listen 80;

    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name www.domain.com
    listen 443 ssl;

    /* SSL Stuff */

    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    server_name domain.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    listen 443 ssl;
    root /usr/share/nginx/domain.com;

    /* SSL Stuff */

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }


location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME            $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
}

    location ~ /\. {
            deny  all;
    }

}
```

curl-v:

```
curl -v http:/domain.com * 
Rebuilt URL to: http://domain.com/ * 
Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache * 
Trying 175.*.*.*... * 
Connected to domain.com (175.*:*:*) port 80 (#0)
 > GET / HTTP/1.1 > User-Agent: curl/7.38.0 
> Host: domain.com > Accept: */* 
> * Connection #0 to host domain.com left intact 
▒▒
```

Comment: This config is OK. Check if you restated nginx, configured firewall, or something else

Comment: Also, check with `curl -v http://domain.com`

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I restarted several times (I tried changing parts of configs, but nothing helped), my firewall is also okay. When checking with curl I get a weird response: ▒▒ just this - doesn't show the source code like it does with https.

Comment: phpfpm should be up and running and socket should exist in /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock.

Comment: It does. PHP works - I don't think it is a PHP issue. Everything over HTTPS works, no matter if it is php or not. But if I type http:// or just the domain (in which case it should redirect to https) it just downloads a 57 byte small file called "download" - Nginx error.log doesn't show anything either.

Comment: show result of curl command above

Comment: `curl -v http:/domain.com
* Rebuilt URL to: http://domain.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 175.*.*.*...
* Connected to domain.com (175.*:*:*) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: domain.com
> Accept: */*
>
* Connection #0 to host domain.com left intact
▒▒`

Comment: Put it into post. Is it your server ip? Where is server response part?

Comment: I put it into the post. That's all I get when I try the command. It ends with that weird symbol (aka downloading that extensionless file) What do you mean by "is it your server ip?"?

Comment: What happens when you have it listen on port 80 http rather than https?

Comment: The same. It's the http that doesn't work for some reason and triggers this strange download of that weird file. I can't even see anything in the logs, either. This is ridiculous.

Comment: The IP you hide in curl's output.

Comment: Yea, of course it is my server.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found out what caused the problem: I was using `listen 80 http2;` in my vhost config which apparently [doesn't work](https://http2.github.io/faq/#does-http2-require-encryption). After I removed http2 from said line it is now working normally again!

Comment: This would have been easy for people to spot, if it had been in your question. You should not omit anything important next time you ask a question.

Comment: I didn't omit anything. How should I been able to know it beforehand? Wouldn't have needed to ask if I knew. But whatever, I sorted it out and that's what matters.

Comment: You omitted whatever part of your configuration contained `listen 80 http2;` which you say was the problem. That made this impossible for anyone else to figure out.

Comment: So glad you posted this question and followed with your solution! I just encountered this and had no idea what was causing the seemingly random file download. Removing `http2` from the one non-SSL site on the server worked!

Comment: I looked everywhere for this, thank you! It would be nice if NGiNX would throw a config warning when this is detected.